# AutoMapper : Open - Closed Principle

Tags: c#, reflection, automapper, open-closed-principle, automapper-6

I got the code from the given link

[AutoMapper Code for Open Closed Principle Code](https://ppolyzos.com/2015/09/29/map-one-object-to-another-using-automapper/)

I am trying to use it in my project but I am stuck due to Static API has been removed from AutoMapper version 4.2.0. For reference [see this](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/21/removing-the-static-api-from-automapper/)

Please can any one help me how to implement the below code's in latest version of Automapper.

1. `Mapper.CreateMap(TSource, TDestination)`

   ```
   private void RegisterStandardMappings(IEnumerable<Type> types)
   {
       var maps = (from t in types
                   from i in t.GetInterfaces()
                   where i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMapForm<>)
                         && !t.IsAbstract
                         && !t.IsInterface
                   select new
                   {
                       Source = i.GetGenericArguments()[0],
                       Destination = t
                   }).ToArray();

       foreach (var map in maps)
       {
           //Need to optimize below line with current version.
           Mapper.CreateMap(map.Source, map.Destination);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Getting `IConfiguration` as it has been changed to `IConfigurationProvider`

   ```
   private void ReverseCustomMappings(IEnumerable<Type> types)
   {
       var maps = (from t in types
                   from i in t.GetInterfaces()
                   where typeof(IHaveCustomMappings).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                         && !t.IsAbstract
                         && !t.IsInterface
                   select (IHaveCustomMappings)Activator.CreateInstance(t)).ToArray();

       foreach (var map in maps)
       {
           //Need to optimize below line with current version.
           map.CreateMappings(Mapper.Configuration);
       }
   }

   public interface IHaveCustomMappings
   {
       void CreateMappings(IConfiguration configuration);
   }
   ```

Please need your suggestions - any help with appreciated.

Comment: The static API was added right back in in 4.2.1 fyi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class AutoMapperTrail101_Console_OCP_Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Initialize Automapper 
        AutoMapperConfiguration.Initialize();

        User user = new User()
        {
            Id = 7,
            Name = "Chandrahas J. Poojari"
        };

        EmployeeViewModel emv = new EmployeeViewModel();

        Mapper.Map(user, emv);

        Console.WriteLine("Employee Id :> " + emv.UserId);
        Console.WriteLine("Employee Name :> " + emv.UserName);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}

class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes();

        //Mapper Initialize only once
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = false;

            RegisterStandardMappings(types, cfg);
            RegisterReverseMappings(types, cfg);
            ReverseCustomMappings(types, cfg);

        });
    }

    private static void RegisterStandardMappings(IEnumerable<Type> types, IMapperConfigurationExpression mce)
    {
        var maps = (from t in types
                    from i in t.GetInterfaces()
                    where i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMapFrom<>)
                          && !t.IsAbstract
                          && !t.IsInterface
                    select new
                    {
                        Source = i.GetGenericArguments()[0],
                        Destination = t
                    }).ToArray();

        foreach (var map in maps)
        {
            mce.CreateMap(map.Source, map.Destination);
        }
    }

    private static void RegisterReverseMappings(IEnumerable<Type> types, IMapperConfigurationExpression mce)
    {
        var maps = (from t in types
                    from i in t.GetInterfaces()
                    where i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMapTo<>)
                          && !t.IsAbstract
                          && !t.IsInterface
                    select new
                    {
                        Source = t,
                        Destination = i.GetGenericArguments()[0]
                    }).ToArray();

        foreach (var map in maps)
        {
            mce.CreateMap(map.Source, map.Destination);
        }
    }

    private static void ReverseCustomMappings(IEnumerable<Type> types, IMapperConfigurationExpression mce)
    {
        var maps = (from t in types
                    from i in t.GetInterfaces()
                    where typeof(IHaveCustomMappings).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                          && !t.IsAbstract
                          && !t.IsInterface
                    select (IHaveCustomMappings)Activator.CreateInstance(t)).ToArray();

        foreach (var map in maps)
        {
            map.CreateMappings(mce);
        }
    }     
}`

interface IMapFrom<T> { }

interface IMapTo<T> { }

interface IHaveCustomMappings { void CreateMappings(IMapperConfigurationExpression mce); }

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeViewModel : IMapFrom<User>, IHaveCustomMappings
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public void CreateMappings(IMapperConfigurationExpression mce)
    {
        mce.CreateMap<User, EmployeeViewModel>()
            .ForMember("UserId", opt => { opt.MapFrom("Id"); })
            .ForMember("UserName", opt => { opt.MapFrom("Name"); });
    }
}
```

@AutoMapper 
Please improve the code if required.....